# Simple Membership Admin Accout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am working on my first ASP.Net MVC 4 application and now stuck with one simple use case.

I need to authenticate one single user (Admin) so that he/she can log in to admin area to perform certain tasks. Though the ASP.Net internet project template has Account controller using simple membership but that seems to have much more than what I actually need. For instance, I don't really need the user registration functionality and user roles. My requirements are fairly simple, just to store one single user in database, give him the options to update his info like password, email etc and grant him access to admin area (admin controller and actions).
What I can't figure out is

1. Are simple membership or other asp.net membership provider my only options for this simple scenario.
2. If not what other option do I have in order to use `[Authorize]` to secure admin actions

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom method to grab the user and their stored role, then evaluate it in your controller.  So, for instance:

```
public ActionResult GetAdminPage()
{
    var loggedInUserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    var user = somesortofproviderlookupmethod(loggedInUserName);

    // Assume user is a bool and is true
    if (user)
    {
        return view("AdminPage");
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is whether or not HttpContext.User requires membership.  Perhaps someone can shed some light.  If so, perhaps you could send the username from the view, but then of course you're trusting the client.  So how you are doing user authentication would change this answer somewhat.

Personally, I like membership.  It's clean, easy, fast and can be scaled nicely if you end up having additional requirements.  Doing something like this would be even easier with membership, since then you can actually use Roles.GetRolesForUser(); and only return the admin view if they contain the role you are looking for.

Comment: I have not implemented simple membership in any of my test project, though read some articles and to me the OAuth and roles sound like unnecessary extra overhead

Comment: You need to have something to recognize that a user is logged in.  Membership makes it easy. OAuth is extremely powerful but is most likely more complicated than what you are looking for.  I think simple membership would be the easiest unless you're planning on rolling your own which I think would be a good deal more complicated than adding ASP.NET Membership in the first place :)

Comment: Though working in ASP.NET webforms for quite some time now but since came from php background, I never used asp.net membership providers. Normally stored logged in userid in session after authentication in order to identify him.

Comment: That's definitely an option.  I'm just not sure it's the most robust solution, or even the most preferred solution.  In my experience, most .NET professionals prefer membership or OAuth over storing the user id in session.  And on another note, in the MVC pattern session plays a much smaller role than it does in PHP and especially in ASP.NET webforms.  As such, I try to avoid session as much as possible in my MVC apps

Comment: May be I am wrong coz I don't have enough experience of ASP.NET mvc and membership providers but I thought ASP.NET MVC (as opposed to web forms) will give me the ability to do things the way I wanted and not restrict me to some limited options. Why should I be forced to learn simple (not so simple) or difficult membership providers when the only requirement is to store some data in db retrieve it and match in order to authenticate/authorize some one.

Comment: It doesn't restrict you at all :).  I was just mentioning the preferred way of doing things.  If you want to roll your own authentication system and store the userId in session, you are more than able to.  In that instance, just retrieve the UserId from session with var userId = Session["UserId"];, and then look up the user by the user id to determine if they have sufficient privileges.  At that point, the code I posted in my answer above is still perfectly valid to determine whether or not you want to render the view for the user.  Hope that helps!